# Getting error when creating simple PUT request using Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to learn sequelize.js and I am getting this TypeError for the update methodd:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

I am trying to get the params of the route and change the values of it. Im trying to get a username and change the username and password of it. Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var model = require("../models/employer_model")(sequelize);
    var Employer = model.Employer;
    return {
        create: function (req, res) {
            if (req.body.username && req.body.password != null) {
                var newEmployer = {
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: req.body.password
                }

            Employer.create(newEmployer).success(function () {
                res.send(200);
                res.json(req.dataValues);
            });} else {
                res.send(406);
            }
        },
        get: function (req, res) {
            Employer.findAll().success(function (employers) {
                res.send(employers);                
            });
        },
        update: function (req, res) {
            Employer.req.params.id = req.body;
            Employer.save().success(function (employers){
                res.send(200);
                res.json(req.dataValues);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Here is server.js

```
// app dependencies
var express = require("express");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();
var models = require("./models"); 

//sequalize initialization
var sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://rahul:jobletics@localhost:5432/jobletics");
var employerRoute = require("./routes/employer_route")(sequelize);

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

models.sequelize.sync().success(function (err) {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 5000');
    app.get("/employer", employerRoute.get);
    app.post("/employer", employerRoute.create);
    app.put("/employer/:id", employerRoute.update);
    app.listen(5000);
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably `Employer.req` is undefined.

Comment: what should the username be then?

Comment: Show pls your app.js(where express init)

Comment: pls see now I updateed it

Answer (score 0):

For what i get you're trying to set the `params` of a model and save an instance. You should first get the instance that you want to update/save.

[For updating instance.](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/#updating-saving-persisting-an-instance)

If you want to build an instance and them save it you also [examples](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/#building-a-non-persistent-instance).

Hope this helps.

Comment: My point is, "Employer.req.params.id = req.body" you're changing the model of the table instead off getting an instance and save it. Employer.req. Does not have params only a instance of that table. You can get that instance creating it a new one with (build or create) or you can fetch to the DB with find or findall

Comment: So you're saying first create an instance of employer in the update method then use that instance to same new params to? But how will that instance refer to the object that's being changed/updated.

Comment: I'm assuming you already have you're model defined, for example: 
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});  The instance that I'm talking represents a row in you're table in the DB. To change this row you need to fetch it from the DB, this will be you're instance and to save again to the DB you must call save or update, where you can see in the http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/#building-a-non-persistent-instance

Comment: Yes this is my model and ill try what you are saying 'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var Employer = sequelize.define("employer", {
        username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { notNull: true } },
        password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { notNull: true } }
    });
    return {
        Employer: Employer
    };
};

Comment: Sequelizejs documentation has several examples, take a look on them. It may save you some headaches

Answer (score 0):

```
Employer.req.params.id = req.body;
```

My guess would be that `Employer.req` is undefined here